# In auto scrolling UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath not triggered by contentOffset

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, tvos

I am attempting to create an auto scrolling UICollectionView (each cell has an image and a string). The scrolling works fine using `contentOffset` but since `cellForItem` is never triggered new/non-visible cells never load. I do not want to use `scrollToItem`...`contentOffset` allows for a slow scrolling effect. I also can't use anything that requires a duration because I want this to run until the view is changed by the user. Here is the code I'm using:

```
func configAutoScrollTimer() {
    signInTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.03, target: self, selector: #selector(autoScrollView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func deconfigAutoScrollTimer() {
    signInTimer.invalidate()
    scrollX = 0
}

@objc func autoScrollView() {
    scrollX += 1

    let offsetPoint = CGPoint(x: scrollX, y: 0)
    collectionView.contentOffset = offsetPoint
    collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

`configureAutoSrollTimer()` is called when the view is loaded. Any ideas on how to get the non-visible cells to load?

Comment: This code works fine in my test project.  There must be something else in code you haven't shown here.  Perhaps something in the setup of the collection view or it's cells.  When you say that the cells that are off screen are not loaded when the UI loads what do you mean?  Do you mean when the collection view is first shown before the scrolling begins?

Comment: he means automatic scrolling with offset doesn't trigger cellForRow so no new cell shows

Comment: yes, thank you. I should have reiterated that in the body. Edited the question to clarify

Comment: Are you sure you have enough contents? Since you are increasing content offset, it will keep scrolling even though you have no cells to load.

Comment: yes, i have a lot more content.

Answer (score 0):

Hook the width constraint of the collectionView as IBOutlet

and do this in viewDidLayoutSubviews

```
 self.collectionViewWithCon.constant = numOfCells*cellWidth
```

Edit:

```
@objc func autoScrollView() {
   self.collectionViewLeadCon.constant -= 1.0
   self.collectionViewWithCon.constant += cellWidth
   collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
 }
```

Comment: there is no width constraint. I have, leading/trailing/bottom to superview and a height.

Comment: by default collectionView inherits from scrollview give it screen width and change it as in answer and see if cell loads or not , the idea is i need to stretch width of collectionview to draw cells even out of screen , i assume from answer that it's horizontal scrolling

Comment: setting a very high width would work but not ideal. this is for an apple tv app on a screen that will be open for about an hour. That means this will be scrolling (horizontally) for at least an hour. I'd have to set the width way too high and that would load way too many cells at once. there has to be a way to trigger `cellForItem` to load another cell in on the fly

Comment: Ok ,then change width gradually in timer callback

Comment: this invalidates the `conetentOffset` resetting it to 0,0

Comment: instead of using content offset drag the leading constraint and play with it also