# I want to create an auto scroll tableview using swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, autoscroll

What I would like to make ultimately is uitableview, which automatically scrolls down.

The total number of lines is set to 25 lines, and it scrolls slowly from line 1 to line 25, and when it reaches the end, it returns to line 1 and scrolls again.

https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel
I want to automatically scroll the UITableView like MarqueeLabel.
(I'll scroll vertically, not horizontally.)

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, so try looking at the functions there to set the content offset. In particular, `setContentOffset(_:animated:)` may be useful.

Comment: Thanks, Smith

Your feedback is very helpful.

I found this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233356/in-auto-scrolling-uicollectionview-cellforitematindexpath-not-triggered-by-conte

It's the solution what I want to do.

 Again, thank u,